# sequelizejs upsert throw SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near ","

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using sequelizejs upsert with postgres, please find my code below.

```
    var upsertTranscript = function(tenant_url, dbHash, cb) {
  orm.getTenantDB(tenant_url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
      logger.warn("Error while getting the tenant db for URL : ", tenant_url);
      cb(err, null);
    } else {
      console.log("transcript_schema_path: ", transcript_schema_path)
      logger.debug("Created DB object for tenant : ", tenant_url)
      var transcript = orm.import(db, transcript_schema_path);
      var hash =  {
        asset_id: dbHash.assetId,
        tenant_url: dbHash.tenant_url,
        file_name: dbHash.file_name,
        uri: dbHash.uri,
        state: dbHash.state,
        payload: dbHash.payload || {},
        duration: dbHash.duration || 0,
        guid: dbHash.guid || ""
      };
      console.log("Trying to upsert : ", hash)
      transcript.upsert(hash, {logging: true}).spread(function(t) {
        if(t) {
          logger.info("Transcript creation success for tenant : " +  dbHash.tenant_url)
          cb(null, t)
        } else {
          logger.warn("Transcript creation failure for tenant : " + dbHash.tenant_url)
          cb(new Error("Transcript creation failure for tenant : " + dbHash.tenant_url), null)
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

This code throws exception

> ```
> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near ","  
>   at Query.formatError (/vagrant/boxer/node_modules/kaybus-utils/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:433:14)  
>   at null.<anonymous> (/vagrant/boxer/node_modules/kaybus-utils/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:108:19)  
>   at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)  
>   at Query.handleError (/vagrant/boxer/node_modules/kaybus-utils/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:108:8)
> ```

What am I doing wrong?
Further I couldn't find full example for upsert, I will be grateful If any one provide me a upsert example as well.

Sequelize logs

Executing (default): CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.sequelize_upsert() RETURNS integer AS $func$ BEGIN INSERT INTO "kbank"."transcriptions" ("asset_id","tenant_url","file_name","uri","payload","state","duration","guid","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ('5','abcd','file_name','uri',,'RECEIVED_FROM_Q',0,'','2015-09-10 10:16:00.226 +00:00','2015-09-10 10:16:00.226 +00:00'); RETURN 1; EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN UPDATE "kbank"."transcriptions" SET "asset_id"='5',"tenant_url"='abcd',"file_name"='file_name',"uri"='uri',"payload"=,"state"='RECEIVED_FROM_Q',"duration"=0,"guid"='',"updated_at"='2015-09-10 10:16:00.226 +00:00'; RETURN 2; END; $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; SELECT * FROM pg_temp.sequelize_upsert();

Comment: Could you please post logs from sequelize (sql queries)?

Comment: I don't know anything about sequelizejs, but native `UPSERT` support was introduced in PostrgreSQL 9.5, which is currently in Alpha 2.